# SDL Contacts and Partners in UAE to Upgrade Tridion 8.1 to Site 9

Tags: upgrade

We want to Upgrade SDL web 8.1 to Tridion Site 9, whom we can contact in UAE as the vendor to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, why upgrade to 9.0? why not 9.6?, do you know the latest version of Tridion Sites is 9.6.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for information on services.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExchange, Please reach out to RWS Support, they get in touch with the EMEA Account Manager and Engagement Officer to give the details of UAE Partners.

Answer (score 2):

In case of technical issues, you can directly raise a support case in the customer support portal. The customer support team can assist you with the technical challenges.

You can also reach out to me directly at bkaliparambil@rws.com and I shall assist you with the right contacts in the UAE.